# The torus is connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $T^2=S^1 \times S^1$ be a torus, where $S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is the unit circle. Is $T^2$ connected? If so, how does one show this?

Comment: Tell us what you tried or don't understand.

Comment: Looks connected to me.

Comment: I was able to show the lemma ($X$ connected, $f:X\to Y$ continuous and surjective $\implies Y$ connected) as well as the lemma ($X$ connected $\iff \emptyset$ and $X$ are the only clopen sets in $X$). Intuitively suspecting that $T^2$ is connected (consider a store-bought donut for verification), I'm wondering whether there is a surjective continuous map $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to T^2$ or whether I need to use a different strategy.

Comment: Product of connected spaces is connected; or use path-connectedness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:  the torus is the continuous image of the connected space the unit square $S$ under certain identifications $\sim$.  The projection $p:S\to S/\sim \cong T^2$ is a quotient map and hence continuous.  (The identifications are of the opposite sides of the square.)

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer that somewhat follows the results we have seen in my topology course so far. For this we use a couple of definitions:

> **Definitions.**
>
> > A topological space $X$ is called **connected**, if there does not exist any decomposition $X = U \cup V$ into non-empty, disjoint subsets $U,V \subseteq X$.
>
> > A topological space $X$ is called **path-connected**, if $\forall x,y \in X$ there exists a continuous map $\gamma:[a,b] \to X$ with $[a,b] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $\gamma(a)=x,\,\gamma(b)=y$.

**Proof.**
We make use of some results that can be proven independently. First, we notice that

> For $n \geq 1$ we have that the $n$-sphere $S^n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \mid \|x\|_2 = 1\}$ is path-connected.

Now, because of the fact

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. $X$ and $Y$ are path-connected $\iff X \times Y$ is path-connected.

we can conclude that $S^1 \times S^1$ is path-connected. Finally,

> Path-connected topological spaces are connected.

Hence, $T^2 = S^1 \times S^1$ is connected. QED.